# How to use Angular2 and Typescript in Jsfiddle

Tags: import, module, typescript, angular, jsfiddle

Dummy question ...
I try to code an angular2 (2.0.0-beta.6) app in Typescript in jsfiddle.
I know that there is other solution online but ...
In fact, my example is very small and the problem is on import module :

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

I got the following error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I try to add some dependencies (require, system ...) but it doesn't work.
And there is no more Self-Executing bundle for recent version (beta-6) of Angular2 (angular2.sfx.dev.js).

Some tests :
    https://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/q8bwosfn/1/
    https://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/q8bwosfn/3/
    https://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/q8bwosfn/4/
    https://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/q8bwosfn/5/
    https://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/q8bwosfn/6/

Comment: Plunkr is much more convenient for this: http://plnkr.co/edit/duastrVR5HUgJUgr3uBf?p=info

Comment: For plunker, I use [this link](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html) from angular.io which will redirect you to plunker with appropriate files already added. It always had the latest angular version. Very convenient.

Comment: The OP asked about JS Fiddle, but of the plunkr links, this one by @Abdulrahman is the best because it includes routing and the new `@angular/forms`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Plunker you can just use the menu

```
New > Angularjs > 2.0.x (TS)
```

to get a minimal working Angular2 application

**Router**

If you want to use the router add in `config.js`

```
'@angular/router': {
  main: 'router.umd.js',
  defaultExtension: 'js'
},
```

`<base href=".">` as first child in the `<head>` of `index.html` might be necessary as well.

To switch to `HashLocationStrategy` change `main.ts` from

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {App} from './app';

bootstrap(App, [])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

to

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {App} from './app';
import {provide} from '@angular/core'
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

bootstrap(App, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HasLocationStrategy}])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I upvoted this because starting from the Plunker menu is good but an even better option is https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html .  It is maintained by the Angular team (not the Plunker team) so it's more current. For instance as of this writing it includes routing as well as the new `@angular/forms`, neither of which the default `Plunker > Angularjs > 2.0 (TS)` workspace has.

Comment: @BeetleJuice, just FYI, link is no longer valid. Angular team is not very consistent in their maintenance.

Answer (score 8):

If you are not tied to `JS Fiddle`, consider `Plunker` instead.  The Angular devs keep a bare workspace up to date with new Angular releases at [this link](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html).

It is more current than even Plunker's own Angular 2 setup (which you can access from the Plunker menu: `New > AngularJS > 2.0.x (TS)`

The downside: that setup is in TypeScript, so if you wish to develop with vanilla Javascript (ES5 or ES6), your best bet is to use the Plunker menu option instead.

Comment: This one is better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137028/angular2-on-jsfiddle-how-to-include-ts-file#41139595

Comment: They don't do it anymore, at least not on that link, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need also to include SystemJS JS file. I saw that you missed it. All these includes are necessary:

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.3/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.3/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.3/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

You also need then to configure `SystemJS` with the following code and then import your main module containing the bootstrap function:

```js
System.config({
  transpiler: 'typescript', 
  typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
  packages: {
    'app': {
      defaultExtension: 'ts'
    }
  } 
});
System.import('app/main')
.then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Comment: It doesn't work ... i tried everythings with typscript, javascript ...
https://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/q8bwosfn/8/  KO
https://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/q8bwosfn/9/  KO
https://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/q8bwosfn/10/  KO
https://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/q8bwosfn/11/  KO

Comment: Honnestly, I'm not very confortable with jsFiddle but from what I saw, you should define (if possible) one area for JavaScript that will contain your SystemJS configuration and one for your TypeScript content (component definition and bootstrap). You must be aware that based on the SystemJS configuration above, the module resolution will be done by path. This means that `app/main` must be something that can be resolved by jsFiddle (`app/main.ts`). This would correspond to your TypeScript area.

Comment: If it's not possible to do that, I think that it will be difficult to use Angular2 application in the tool :-(