# Angular2 on JSFiddle – How to include .ts file?

Tags: angular, jsfiddle, plunker

I am using jsFiddle for the first time. I do not know how to include all my files in it. Currently when running the fiddle it returns a 404. How do i link my local ts file to make it run.

My fiddle is located [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Unnati/kje2sr61/). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
 <script>
    System.config({
      transpiler: 'typescript',
      typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
      packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
    });
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

This returns:

> angular2-polyfills.js:1243 Error: XHR error (404 NOT FOUND) loading
>   https://fiddle.jshell.net/Unnati/kje2sr61/show/app/main.ts(…)

Comment: Would you consider using a plunker instead?

Comment: yes it will also be ok.

Comment: I've provided an example below. Does it suit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an Angular2 starter project in a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/F5lDxrDUFlNQQZimUhk9?p=preview

It's bootstrapped with a simple `AppComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h2>Hello World</h2>`,
  providers: []
})
export class App implements ngAfterViewInit{
  name:any;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(){
  }
}
```

all `system.config` type of configs are set. If you want to change it and save for later use just click "Fork" at the top of the screen.

**Update:** Plunker now has a default template option for Angular 2.0.x

You can click the arrow the right of New -> Angular -> 2.0.x

Comment: I have forked the plunker link provided above, whenever I make any edit it open the result in a new tab which is slowing me down in writing the code.

Comment: @SiddharthSharma seems like it's a bug with zone.js version https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plunker/cPEILSWfjS4. Upgraded it to 0.6.25.

Comment: If someone is facing the problem of code result opening in new tab, the same can be fixed temporarily by disabling auto save in bottom in the settings tab of plunkr. After this you will need to save manually though.

Answer (score 0):

You can click the dropdown NEW and click Angular this will automatically generate an angular4 template.